# socket.io connecting from Firefox and Safari but not from Chrome. Also exhibiting weird behaviour with browser refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, sockets

I'm putting together a socket.io implementation for use with nodejs.

The application works great on most devices using various browsers, but on some devices Chrome is unable to connect to the socket server, throwing this console error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss:<mydomain.com>:3000/socket.io/?EIO4&transport=websocket' failed: websocket.js 88
    doOpen    @websocket.js:88
    open      @transport.js:46
    open      @socket.js:197
```

...and some more lines like that. (I've changed my actual domain name to <mydomain.com> for the sake of this post.)

What's odd is that on at least one device, both Firefox and Chrome can connect just fine. But on some devices only Firefox will connect while Chrome throws the error above.

What's even odder is that on a device whose Chrome browser fails to connect to the socket server, if I manually type in https://<mydomain.com>:3000/socket.io/EIO=4&transport=polling into the address bar, I get the expected output:

```
0{"sid":"j53jSJFo3j_0393mc0sjai4209", "upgrades": ["websocket"], "pingInterval":25000, "pingTimeout":200000}
```

Now here's where it gets *really* weird: on a device that fails to connect to the socket server, if I remove the io options when instantiating the io server connection, then refresh the client browser, it throws a CORS error — which is expected — but then if I undo the code change and refresh the client browser again, *it starts working*.

So it starts off not working in Chrome, but then starts working if I change the code *then change the code back* to what it was when it wasn't working the first time/pageload.

Here's the server code:

```
const { Server }     = require("socket.io");
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const https = require('https');
const server = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('<privkey_location>'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('<cert_location>'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('<chain_location>'),
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
},app);
global.io = new Server(server);

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

io.on('connection', (client) => {
    client.emit('hlo');
});
```

...and the client page:

```
<script src="https://www.netwaffles.com:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var srv = io('<mydomain.com>:3000' , { transports : ['websocket'], secure: true });

srv.on('hlo', function() { alert('Connected.'); });

</script>
```

So that all works as expected on most devices/browsers. It even works in Chrome on some devices.

But on devices whose Chrome browser fails to connect at first, if I change this line:

```
var srv = io('<mydomain.com>:3000' , { transports : ['websocket'], secure: true });
```

...to this:

```
var srv = io('<mydomain.com>:3000');
```

...and refresh the browser, it still fails to connect, except now the error is a CORS error (as expected would be the case).

But then if I change that line back to this:

```
var srv = io('<mydomain.com>:3000' , { transports : ['websocket'], secure: true });
```

...and then I refresh the Chrome browser again, it connects to the socket server after a few seconds of trying, and the application in general starts to work just as normally as it does on other devices right from the start.

THIS SEEMS BANANAS TO ME.

If I close the client browser once it's working, then open the browser up to start a fresh session, when I load the page it's back to not working again. I can refresh the page a hundred times without it starting to work, but then if I perform the rigmarole above (remove the io options from the code, refresh the client browser, then undo the code change and refresh the client browser again with the original code) it starts working and continues to work until I close the browser again and start a new session.

Meanwhile on most devices it works fine the first time, with no fiddling, regardless of what browser is being used.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this, and how to make socket.io work reliably in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a workaround, in case anyone else hits a wall with this issue.

I don't consider this a proper fix as it doesn't address the cause of the problem, but it does seem to reliably negate the symptom (in that it makes the page load properly on Chrome at first pageload).

The workaround is just a cheeky little pre-fill to emulate the edit-code-and-reload-page-then-undo-code-edit-and-reload-again rigmarole in OP. Basically I just changed this line of code:

```
srv = io('<mydomain>:3000' , { transports : ['websocket'], secure: true });
```

...to this:

```
var srv = {};
if (!!window.chrome) {
    srv = io('<mydomain>:3000');
}
srv = io('<mydomain>:3000' , { transports : ['websocket'], secure: true });
```

If anyone stumbles across this post who has a more thorough understanding of socket.io and can explain why this workaround is needed for Chrome, and ideally how to address the problem properly instead of side-stepping it, that would be excellent!

In the meantime this workaround seems to make things work.